# force visual studio linker to keep name mangling

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll, linker

i am working on a dll proxy project and i am having problem with forcing the visual studio linker to use the mingling name of the functions.

in my def file i have :

`EXPORTS
_ap_abort_on_oom@0=__E__0__ @1`

but after building the solution the function in the dll is :

```
_ap_abort_on_oom
```

when i run the my original prog i get an error that _ap_abort_on_oom@0 not found. i am using the [wrappit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16541/Create-your-Proxy-DLLs-automatically) project
how do i change the linker settings so it will use the decorated names?

Comment: That looks fishy. It's C mangling, and the number after the @ signals the argument count IIRC. Your proxy funcion should also be @0, i.e. accept the same number of arguments. Once you've fixed that, this problem might very well go away.

Comment: i cannot alter the original dll, i only have the def file and new cpp to create new dll

Comment: I know. But you **did** write the new DLL, and it should match the name mangling of the old DLL. The `EXPORTS` rule can fix name differences, not a difference in number of arguments.

Comment: in my new dll : 
hL = LoadLibrary(L".\\libhttpd2.dll");|
p[0] = GetProcAddress(hL,"_ap_abort_on_oom@0");

extern "C" __declspec(naked) void __stdcall __E__0__()
 {
 __asm
  {
  jmp p[0*4];
  }
 }

and not working

Comment: Why don't you just call that function `_ap_abort_on_oom` like the callers expect?

Comment: because when the original program will try to call the function it will try to call it as it written in the original dll and not in the linked one.

Answer (score 2):

This question (and others like it) relate to creating proxy DLLs automatically using the [Code Project WRAPPIT](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16541/Create-your-Proxy-DLLs-automatically) tool.

The solution is to always declare the wrapper function to be __stdcall so that it gets decorated with a leading _ and trailing @0, and then use that in the .def file so that the original function decoration (if any) is preserved.

(When/if you replace the wrapper with a real function, you need to remember to change the call convention from __stdcall to the one needed, as well as remove __declspec(naked), add argument declarations etc.)

Wrapper .cpp snipet:

```
// _OriginalFunction@12
extern "C" __declspec(naked) void __stdcall __E__0__()
    {
    __asm
        {
        jmp p[0*4];
        }
    }
```

.def file:

```
EXPORTS
_OriginalFunction@12=___E__0__@0 @1
etc.
```

I modified my version of the WRAPPIT tool to do this automatically:

```
165c165
<                       fprintf(fdef,"%s=%s @%u\r\n",v[i].en,v[i].in,v[i].o);
---
>                       fprintf(fdef,"%s=_%s@0 @%u\r\n",v[i].en,v[i].in,v[i].o);
167c167
<                       fprintf(fdef,"%s=%s @%u NONAME\r\n",v[i].en,v[i].in,v[i].o);
---
>                       fprintf(fdef,"%s=_%s@0 @%u NONAME\r\n",v[i].en,v[i].in,v[i].o);
225c225
<               fprintf(fcpp,"// %s\r\nextern \"C\" __declspec(naked) void %s %s()\r\n",v[i].en,argv[3],v[i].in);
---
>               fprintf(fcpp,"// %s\r\nextern \"C\" __declspec(naked) void %s %s()\r\n",v[i].en,"__stdcall",v[i].in);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your mangled name has a `@` character in it.  That is never going to work.  The `@` character is reserved as the separator between the name and the ordinal.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3.aspx

Comment: anyway to walk around?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `.def` file, use the `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute. Here's an example:

**test.cpp:**

```
__declspec(dllexport) void foo(int a,int b) {
}
```

**Build:**

```
C:\tmp>cl /c /nologo test.cpp
test.cpp

C:\tmp>link.exe /nologo /dll /out:test.dll test.obj
   Creating library test.lib and object test.exp
```

**Test:**

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file test.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for test.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    54FD7DE4 time date stamp Mon Mar 09 11:03:00 2015
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001000 ?foo@@YAXHH@Z
```

Note that the mangling is present in the `foo()` function exported in the DLL.

Comment: i need to keep the convention of the name mingling ... my original dll has _ap_abort_on_oom@0 function so i need the new dll to have it too